# Check if the set is connected or not

Tags: analysis, connectedness

I want to check if the following set is connected.

$$\displaystyle{S=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^2 : x_2\cos x_1=\sin x_1\}}$$

This set is equivalent to $\displaystyle{\{x\in \mathbb{R}^2 : x_2=\tan x_1\}}$, isn't it?

The tangens function is not continuous on whole $\mathbb{R}$. Does this mean that we can write this set as a union of two non-empty sets?

Or do we have to do something else?

Comment: Every set with more than two elements can be written as a union of two nonempty subsets. What you're looking for is two *disjoint nonempty open* subsets of $S$ (open in the subspace topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}^2$, that is). The answer is yes, you can find two such sets. Consider $\{(x_1, x_2)\in S : x_1 < \pi/2\}$ and $\{(x_1, x_2)\in S : x_1 > \pi/2\}$, for example.

Comment: To directly answer your question, you cannot assume that just because a function is not continuous that its graph is not connected. Consider the [topologist's sine curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve) for a counterexample.

Comment: We choose $\pi/2$ because at this point the tangens function is not defined, right? @MichaelLee

Comment: More precisely, we choose it because there is no $x_2$ such that $x_2\cos(\pi/2) = \sin(\pi/2)$, so the intersection of $S$ with the line $\{(x_1, x_2) : x_1 = \pi/2\}$ is empty, and we can partition $S$ into the sets I described.

Comment: I see! Thank you very much!! :-) @MichaelLee

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be given by $f(x_1,x_2)=x_1$. Notice $f(S)= \bigcup\limits_{k \text{ odd integer}} (k\pi, k+2\pi)$.

Since $f$ is continuous and $f(S)$ is not connected we conclude $S$ is not connected.

Comment: How did you find $f(S)$ ?

Comment: its not hard to see $x2$ is uniquely determines if $\cos(x_1)\neq 0$ and when $\cos(x_1)\neq -$ we have $\sin(x_1)\neq 0$ and so there is no $x_2$.